# How integrate Paytm Subscription payment (recurring payments) in android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, payment-gateway, recurring-billing, paytm

I have implemented paytm payment gateway (All in one sdk) , Now I want to provide recurring payment (Subscription payment methods) for my users.
how Should  I implement it? Please someone explain to me in detail I'm new to this & It is very necessary for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to Paytm Developer Portal for the same. On the home page, you will find a tab of API reference where you would see Subscriptions. In subscriptions, you will get an Initiate Subscription API which can be used for recurring payment. In case of any issues please raise a ticket on the Contact Us of Paytm Developer portal